# Using std::unique_ptr and lambdas to advance a state of an object

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr, scopeguard

When advancing the state of an object, use of `std::swap` works well for simple objects and pointer swaps. For other in place actions, [`Boost.ScopeExit`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html) works rather well, but it's not terribly elegant if you want to share exit handlers across functions. Is there a C++11 native way to accomplish something similar to `Boost.ScopeExit` but allow for better code reuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Ab)use `std::unique_ptr`'s custom Deleters as a `ScopeExitVisitor` or Post Condition. Scroll down to ~7th line of `main()` to see how this is actually used at the call site. The following example allows for either `std::function` or lambdas for `Deleter`/`ScopeExitVisitor`'s that don't require any parameters, and a nested class if you do need to pass a parameter to the `Deleter`/`ScopeExitVisitor`.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A {
 public:
  using Type = A;
  using Ptr = Type*;
  using ScopeExitVisitorFunc = std::function<void(Ptr)>;
  using ScopeExitVisitor = std::unique_ptr<Type, ScopeExitVisitorFunc>;

  // Deleters that can change A's private members. Note: Even though these
  // are used as std::unique_ptr<> Deleters, these Deleters don't delete
  // since they are merely visitors and the unique_ptr calling this Deleter
  // doesn't actually own the object (hence the label ScopeExitVisitor).
  static void ScopeExitVisitorVar1(Ptr aPtr) {
    std::cout << "Mutating " << aPtr << ".var1. Before: " << aPtr->var1;
    ++aPtr->var1;
    std::cout << ", after: " << aPtr->var1 << "\n";
  }

  // ScopeExitVisitor accessing var2_, a private member.
  static void ScopeExitVisitorVar2(Ptr aPtr) {
    std::cout << "Mutating " << aPtr << ".var2. Before: " << aPtr->var2_;
    ++aPtr->var2_;
    std::cout << ", after: " << aPtr->var2_ << "\n";
  }

  int var1 = 10;
  int var2() const { return var2_; }

  // Forward declare a class used as a closure to forward Deleter parameters
  class ScopeExitVisitorParamVar2;

 private:
  int var2_ = 20;
};

// Define ScopeExitVisitor closure. Note: closures nested inside of class A
// still have access to private variables contained inside of A.
class A::ScopeExitVisitorParamVar2 {
 public:
  ScopeExitVisitorParamVar2(int incr) : incr_{incr} {}
  void operator()(Ptr aPtr) {
    std::cout << "Mutating " << aPtr << ".var2 by " << incr_ << ". Before: " << aPtr->var2_;
    aPtr->var2_ += incr_;
    std::cout << ", after: " << aPtr->var2_ << "\n";
  }

 private:
  int incr_ = 0;
};

// Can also use lambdas, but in this case, you can't access private
// variables.
//
static auto changeStateVar1Handler = [](A::Ptr aPtr) {
  std::cout << "Mutating " << aPtr << ".var1 " << aPtr->var1 << " before\n";
  aPtr->var1 += 2;
};

int main() {
  A a;

  std::cout << "a: " << &a << "\n";

  std::cout << "a.var1: " << a.var1 << "\n";
  std::cout << "a.var2: " << a.var2() << "\n";

  { // Limit scope of the unique_ptr handlers. The stack is unwound in
    // reverse order (i.e. Deleter var2 is executed before var1's Deleter).
    A::ScopeExitVisitor scopeExitVisitorVar1(nullptr, A::ScopeExitVisitorVar1);
    A::ScopeExitVisitor scopeExitVisitorVar1Lambda(&a, changeStateVar1Handler);
    A::ScopeExitVisitor scopeExitVisitorVar2(&a, A::ScopeExitVisitorVar2);
    A::ScopeExitVisitor scopeExitVisitorVar2Param(nullptr, A::ScopeExitVisitorParamVar2(5));

    // Based on the control of a function and required set of ScopeExitVisitors that
    // need to fire use release() or reset() to control which visitors are used.
    // Imagine unwinding a failed but complex API call.
    scopeExitVisitorVar1.reset(&a);
    scopeExitVisitorVar2.release(); // Initialized in ctor. Use release() before reset().
    scopeExitVisitorVar2.reset(&a);
    scopeExitVisitorVar2Param.reset(&a);

    std::cout << "a.var1: " << a.var1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "a.var2: " << a.var2() << "\n";
    std::cout << "a.var2: " << a.var2() << "\n";
  }

  std::cout << "a.var1: " << a.var1 << "\n";
  std::cout << "a.var2: " << a.var2() << "\n";
}
```

Which produces:

```
a: 0x7fff5ebfc280
a.var1: 10
a.var2: 20
a.var1: 10
a.var2: 20
a.var2: 20
Mutating 0x7fff5ebfc280.var2 by 5. Before: 20, after: 25
Mutating 0x7fff5ebfc280.var2. Before: 25, after: 26
Mutating 0x7fff5ebfc280.var1 10 before
Mutating 0x7fff5ebfc280.var1. Before: 12, after: 13
a.var1: 13
a.var2: 26
```

On the plus side, this trick is nice because:

- Code used in the Deleters can access private variables
- Deleter code is able to be centralized
- Using lambdas is still possible, though they can only access pubic members.
- Parameters can be passed to the Deleter via nested classes acting as closures
- Not all `std::unique_ptr` instances need to have an object assigned to them (e.g. it's perfectly acceptable to leave unneeded Deleters set to `nullptr`)
- Changing behavior at runtime is simply a matter of calling `reset()` or `release()`
- Based on the way you build your stack it's possible at compile time to change the safety guarantees on an object when the scope of the `std::unique_ptr`(s) go out of scope

Lastly, using [`Boost.ScopeExit`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html) you can forward calls to a helper function or use a conditional similar to what the `Boost.ScopeExit` docs suggest with `bool commit = ...;`. Something similar to:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/scope_exit.hpp>

int main() {
  bool commitVar1 = false;
  bool commitVar2 = false;
  BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_ALL(&) {
    if (commitVar1)
      std::cout << "Committing var1\n"
    if (commitVar2)
      std::cout << "Committing var2\n"
  };
  commitVar1 = true;
}
```

and there's nothing wrong with that, but like was asked in the original question, how do you share code without proxying the call someplace else? Use `std::unique_ptr`'s Deleters as `ScopeExitVisitors`.